# security vulnerabilities in using launching activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In Android , I use a Home screen activity which shows all registred items .

when launching the application, my Home screen activity is launched as default.

From settings screen of the application, i can set a password for the app. Once i set the password.  every time i launch the application. it shows my Password screen. 
After entering the password it takes to my Home screen activity.

But from a hacker point of view, even without knowing the password, i can still go to my Home screen when i give this command.

```
    am start -n com.share.device/.device.DeviceListActivity
```

This automatically starts my Home screen activity, even though i have set a password for the application.

How can i restrict the access to the Home screen activity, even if i use the "am start" command.

I dont want anyone to directly access Home screen when there is a password set for the application.
Please suggest how we can rectify this issue.

IntroActivity -> DeviceListActvity

using "am start" command, i can directly start the DeviceListActivity

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".common.IntroActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".device.DeviceListActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Post code and also your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: @Squonk -   
<activity android:name=".common.IntroActivity" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity> <activity android:name=".device.DeviceListActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

Answer (score 0):

Have your login activity set some static variable somewhere.  In the DeviceListActivity, check that variable.  If it isn't set, do not run the activity-  instead launch the login activity and immediately finish() yourself.

This is even better if the value set is something coming from a server, such as a login token if any info is coming from a server.

Comment: How about setting android:exported="false" ?

I found that ..when setting this tag ..and i use am start command , i get java.lang.securityexception.  So does it mean that this issue is fixed?

Comment: That wouldn't prevent the android system itself from starting the non-launcher activity.  Such as from the recents menu.  If he's only worrying about hackers, that's fine.  If he doesn't want it to run because he needs login info from a server and wants to ensure that it isn't someone else running it later from recents, its insufficient.

Comment: =  Unfortunatley, with a rooted phone, android:exported=false doesnt work. I can still access the activity with a rooted phone. Now i feel i need to go wtih your suggestion. Can you tell me more details on how to proceed

Comment: i tried adding a prefernce editor and set a string. But that also doesnt work. After checking password ,it set the preference as true.  When i launch using am start command. it still shows true.

Comment: @GabeSechon  I tried setting a static string . after password  validity is confirmed, i set the static string = Mobileviewer .  Then at the next activity i check for the static string = "".  So when we test using am start command. the static string is "" and so as mentioned above, i finish() the activity and re launch the password acvtivity.  Is my implementation correct?